# How to define a connection on the dual bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

I'm reading Terence Tao's blog and he says

> Once one has a connection on a bundle $V$, one automatically can
>   define a connection on the dual bundle $V^*$.

Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you are talking about linear connections ("covariant derivatives").

Assume that $V$ is a vector bundle over $M$. The dual connection is uniquely defined by requiring that it satisfies the product rule with respect to the natural pairing between $V$ and $V^*$. Let $\xi \in \Gamma(V)$ and $\varphi \in \Gamma(V^*)$, and denote by
$$ \left< \varphi, \xi \right> = \varphi(\xi ) \in C^\infty(M) $$
the natural pairing between the bundles. That is, at each point $p \in M$, you apply the functional $\varphi_p$ to the vector $\xi_p$ to get a number $\varphi_p(\xi_p)=(\varphi(\xi))(p)$.
Then, the dual connection satisfies the "product" rule
$$ \nabla_X \left< \varphi, \xi \right> = X \left< \varphi, \xi \right> = \left< \nabla_X \varphi, \xi \right> + \left< \varphi, \nabla_X \xi  \right> $$
for all $X \in \Gamma(TM)$.

Comment: When define a connection on a vector bundle, we are given a function $f\in\Gamma(V)$ and a vector field $X\in\Gamma(TM)$. But according to your answer, we must be given TWO functions, one in $\Gamma(V)$ and one in $\Gamma(V^*)$, to define a dual connection?..

Comment: No. A connection on $V$ eats a section $\xi \in \Gamma(V)$ and a vector field $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ and returns a section in $\Gamma(V)$. Here, $\varphi$ a section of the dual vector bundle $\Gamma(V^*)$ and so in $\nabla_X \varphi$. Instead of defining it directly, I gave the property that characterizes it. Note, that if you move the second term of the equality on the right to the other side, you understand how the functional $\nabla_X \varphi$ acts on a vector $\xi$ in terms of the connection on $V$, for **any** $\xi$. This defines $\nabla_X \varphi$ uniquely.

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space, how do you define how a functional $\varphi \in V^*$? You say what it does to any vector $v \in V$. That is, you give $\varphi(v) = \left< \varphi, v \right>$. This is the same.

Comment: Oh..Yes, I'm clear now, Thank you!

Comment: Why should the dual connection satisfy this product rule? By the way, on the left hand side of the last equation I believe it is $\mathcal{L}_{X}(\langle \varphi, \xi\rangle)$.

Comment: @PtF: It doesn't have to satisfy it, this is merely a definition but a reasonable one if you think about the situation in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Regarding the left hand side, usually when $f$ is a function, the notations $\nabla_X f$, $\mathcal{L}_X(f)$, $Xf$ and $df(X)$ are all denoting the same thing so you can write it also as $\mathcal{L}_X( \left< \varphi, \xi \right>)$ if you wish.